# Word for someone who helps a leadman or chief

Tags: single-word-requests

According to my observance, I found the following words:

> 1. Helper, one who helps others.
> 2. Assistant, one who assists others.

Are these okay, or should I need other words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called an **[Acolyte](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acolyte)**

> one who attends or assists a leader : follower

Usage examples:

> - The duties of the **acolyte**, as given in the Roman Pontifical, are identical with those mentioned in the Statuta Ecclesiae Antigua of Arles: "It is the duty of **acolytes** to carry the candlesticks, to light the lamps of the church, to administer wine and water for the Eucharist."
> - The office of **acolyte** may have been suggested by the attendant assigned to heathen priests.

Comment: "Acolyte" originally had a purely religious connotation, and its use in a secular context has been somewhat metaphorical. As a native speaker I wouldn't use it unless I was wanting to give a sense of "loyal, dutiful, unquestioning servant". To call a deputy chairperson the "acolyte" of the chairperson could either be a huge compliment or (more likely) a gross insult.

Comment: In the military, especially in the naval services, the Captain's chief assistant is the "XO", or Executive Officer, who is second in command.